# strange MPMoviePlayer problem

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, orientation, mpmovieplayer

I am using mpmovieplayer in my application.I have a button for playing movie witch has an image of play.But when mpmovieplayer plays movie i can see that button on movie player's overlying controlls like when i pause movie i see my play button instead of movie player's default button.Also i have customized navigation bar and i can see that navbar when movie plays instead of default nav bar.I tried hiding button when playing movie but it didn't worked.Does Someone knows about this issue? also i am having cropping of video issues does someone knows about how to handle video orientation i mean i want full video in any orientation recorded video.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that changing the file name from play.png to fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also. The name of the image for play button was kept as play.png
I beleive this is the case with you also. 
Try changing the name of play.png to someother name. I beleive the mediaplayer api internally looks for play.png image for display on the player control.